# How can I find the real part of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis

$k = e^{{1-i\frac{pi}{3}}}$

What I think I should do is expand in Taylor's series, and separate out the i to get a series for both the real part and the imaginary part.
But I am not sure if finding the real series would be the same as "finding the real part"..
Any help here?

Comment: That's just a number. Is there a variable missing in the right hand side?

Answer (score 2):

$$
e^{1-i\frac{\pi}3}=e^{1}\,e^{-i\frac{\pi}3}=e\,\left(\cos(-\frac\pi3)+i\sin(-\frac\pi3)\right)
=e\,(\cos\frac\pi3-i\sin\frac\pi3)=\frac e2-i\frac{\sqrt3}2.
$$
So the real part is $e/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{1-i\frac\pi3}=\frac{e^1}{e^{i\frac\pi3}}=\frac{e}{\cos\frac\pi3+i\cdot\sin\frac\pi3}=\frac{e}{\cos\frac\pi3+i\cdot\sin\frac\pi3}\cdot\frac{\cos\frac\pi3-i\cdot\sin\frac\pi3}{\cos\frac\pi3-i\cdot\sin\frac\pi3}=$$

$$=\frac{e(\cos\frac\pi3-i\cdot\sin\frac\pi3)}{\cos^2\frac\pi3-i^2\cdot\sin^2\frac\pi3}=\frac{e(\cos\frac\pi3-i\cdot\sin\frac\pi3)}{\cos^2\frac\pi3+\cdot\sin^2\frac\pi3}=\frac{e(\cos\frac\pi3-i\cdot\sin\frac\pi3)}1=$$

$$=e(\cos\frac\pi3-i\cdot\sin\frac\pi3)=e\cdot\cos\frac\pi3-e\cdot i\cdot\sin\frac\pi3\iff\Re\left(e^{1-i\frac\pi3}\right)=e\cdot\cos\frac\pi3=e\cdot\frac12=\frac e2$$

Comment: ... or just apply the cis-formula directly to $-\frac{\pi}{3}$.  It's easier.